Gas generated in cooling system, even when the car is off
It's weirder than just a head gasket problem. I promise.
Car is a 1974 VW Bus with an Subaru EJ20 swap. There is a big aluminum radiator mounted in the middle, and a heater core up front. Radiator and heater core are new (I did the swap last year) and all the coolant lines are new.
Symptoms:

Pressure in the cooling system. When the car sits for a day or so, and you open the expansion tank cap, the level rises in the tank and you can hear a pressure release, sometimes it overflows. Note that this happens even if the car isn't run. So I can open the cap and release all the pressure and then put the cap back on, and then not run the car at all and if I come back the next day there is pressure in the system again, and when I open the cap and the expansion tank level rises again and pressure is released. The level changes quite a bit, like several cups, so I don't think it's just the change in ambient temperature.

I've flushed the coolant and replaced it with water, same thing happens.

The coolant smells weird. And the smell is also there after I flushed it and replaced with water. It's almost an organic kinda sulfury smell.

After I flushed the system, the water has some tiny white flakes in it, most likely aluminum oxide.

I've grounded the radiator and the heater core, so I don't think there is electrolysis eating either of them. I've also removed the heater core entirely and no change.

This happens with the battery disconnected as well

Coolant has a TDS count of 81ppm. I have no idea if that's high or normal.

And just for fun: no indications of a headgasket failure. Exhaust gas test of the coolant yielded a negative result (fluid stayed blue) and there is no overheating or coolant temp spikes. Car runs great, always right at 195*. No oil in the coolant. No coolant in the oil. And multiple different radiator caps don't influence anything.


It really seems like something is generating a gas in the system. But how?
Appreciate any advice. In the 10+ years that I've been into cars, I haven't encountered anything like this. It really seems like a chemistry issue of some sort.

This is definitely a weird one. It sounds like you've ruled out all the most common causes already. My best guess would be some sort of dissimilar metal contact causing galvanic corrosion. This happens when two metals with different electrochemical properties contact each other in the presence of an electrolyte. This causes a chemical reaction which will cause one of the metals to corrode. That reaction could also produce hydrogen gas. This is actually how early primitive batteries were created.
The effect depends on the specific metals and the electrolyte involved, but because corrosion is such an important factor in industrial and transportation industries, it's been studied thoroughly, and there are charts and tables to help determine which metals are compatible with each other.
In an older car, the most likely metals you'll encounter will be iron/steel, aluminum, and brass/bronze. Those are fairly spread out on the galvanic series, so it would probably not be hard to accidentally create such a reaction.
You mentioned the engine had been swapped, so it's possible there's some sort of dissimilar metal contact resulting from that swap which wouldn't have occurred in the original car. Maybe somewhere there's a stainless steel part touching an aluminum part, or something similar.
Generally the way this works is you have two dissimilar metal parts which are both exposed to an electrolyte (water with dissolved chemicals in it) and some sort of electrical connection (metal-to--metal contact) between the parts. This doesn't require an external source of electricity, the chemical reaction actually creates the electricity.
Another somewhat gross possibility is that something crawled into the cooling system and died, like a snake or a mouse. The smell would probably not be the same as you'd get from a dead animal lying around, because the heat would alter the chemistry involved, but it would still be an unpleasant smell.

Thanks for the reply. The interesting thing here is that since the original car is aircooled, every piece of the new cooling system is new. The other interesting part is that the engine is aluminum, and the radiator is aluminum. I've bypassed the heater core for now to rule that out (since it does appear to have brass brazing). So the only pieces left are all aluminum, rubber, and plastic. One thing to mention is that the water at my house is hard water, and I did use tap water to fill it. But I do that on a number of cars and they're fine...

You mentioned a sulfur smell, does your water have high sulfur content?

Another somewhat gross possibility is that something crawled into the cooling system and died, like a snake or a mouse. But I'd think that would produce a more noticeable stink.

There is definitely a smell to the water. So a dead animal is sort of where I've landed for an explanation. I tested the pH and it was 11, and alkalinity was extremely high, off the chart. The water felt super soft when I touched it. So I think either a mouse or toad (we have so many of them around...) may have crawled in when I was doing the swap and had things apart.
